# Role derivative of sigmoid function in neural networks

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I try to understand role of derivative of sigmoid function in neural networks. 
[image]

First I plot sigmoid function, and derivative of all points from definition using python. What is the role of this derivative exactly? 
[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

def derivative(x, step):
    return (sigmoid(x+step) - sigmoid(x)) / step

x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 1000)

y1 = sigmoid(x)
y2 = derivative(x, 0.0000000000001)

plt.plot(x, y1, label='sigmoid')
plt.plot(x, y2, label='derivative')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

But I find this:

[image]

source: http://www.ai.mit.edu/courses/6.892/lecture8-html/sld015.htm

And when I plot result of this derivative I get

[image]

Totally another plot. Why? What is the difference of this derivatives?

Plot of second

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def __sigmoid_derivative(x):
    return x * (1 - x)

x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 1000)

y1 = __sigmoid_derivative(x)

plt.plot(x, y1)
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Comment: I don't think you plotted it correctly. Please show me the code that plots the second line. `def derivative(x): sigmoid(x) * (1 - sigmoid(x))` is what it should look like.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I add code to question

Comment: `return x * (1 - x)` this is incorrect. Its the sigmoid function as a whole that should replace the `x` here.

Comment: Hm, I get this code from https://medium.com/technology-invention-and-more/how-to-build-a-multi-layered-neural-network-in-python-53ec3d1d326a

Comment: I have a lot of time so I will go into the details of backpropagation and why the derivative is a necessity.

Comment: @lukassz because, the function assumes that `x` is nothing but `sigmoid(x')` where `x'` is your actual input. See how the function is called. They're passing `output_from_layer_2` which is likely already the squashed output.

Comment: @JahKnows Not required, that is out of the scope of this question. This arises from a simple misunderstanding of another user's code.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ consider the title of the question.

Comment: @JahKnows Please consider the actual question: `Why? What is the difference of this derivatives?`

Comment: @lukassz, if you are interested in further understanding the need for derivatives in neural networks feel free to post a question in the Data Science Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula formula for the derivative of the sigmoid function is given by `s(x) * (1 - s(x))`, where `s` is the sigmoid function.

The advantage of the sigmoid function is that its derivative is very easy to compute - it is in terms of the original function.

```
def __sigmoid_derivative(x):
    return sigmoid(x) * (1 - sigmoid(x))
```

And so you have

[image]

The other alternative you quote, i.e.,

```
def __sigmoid_derivative(x):
    return x * (1 - x)
```

Assumes that `x` is already the output of the sigmoid function, and so it is not to be re-computed the second time.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your plot is incorrect. This should give you the correct plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

def derivative(x, step):
    return (sigmoid(x+step) - sigmoid(x)) / step

def other_derivative(x):
    y = [(1/(1 + np.exp(-i))) * (1 - (1 /(1 + np.exp(-i)))) for i in x]
    return y

x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 1000)

y1 = sigmoid(x)
y2 = derivative(x, 0.0000000000001)
y3 = other_derivative(x)

plt.plot(x, y1, label='sigmoid')
plt.plot(x, y2, label='derivative')
plt.plot(x, y3, label='other derivative')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

[image]